# Listener to automatically detect message from Amazon SQS and retrieve them

Tags: c#, asp.net, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

**Use Case:** I have created a form for entering user details in asp.net. Now after the details are entered, on a button click, the details are entered into the Amazon SQS. After this I have added a listener that has a button "btn_ReceiveMessage". On clicking this button the Message(user details) gets fetched from the Amazon SQS and gets stored in the SQL database.

**Requirement:** Now I want to automate this process. Instead of clicking on the "btn_ReceiveMessage" button, the listener should be able to detect if new messages are added to the SQS queue, and if added then listener should automatically retrieve them.

Is it possible ? Can I maybe use a scheduler for this process or there is some other way ?

Thanks in advance. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've tagged [tag:aws-lambda] in the question, but haven't mentioned it explicitly.  AWS [recently promised](https://twitter.com/sqlbot/status/992232833115713536?s=19) that an SQS → Lambda integration was coming soon... but for now, did you consider using SNS instead?  Publishing a message to SNS can trigger a Lambda function to consume the message.  It's not entirely clear whether that matches your use case, but seems like it might.

Comment: I was not sure whether aws-lambda is usable with Amazon SQS or not, that's why i have used the tag. Thanks for explaining. But I do not want to use SNS along with SQS. I may want to implement a scheduler type structure that can help automate the process with SQS only. Do you have any other suggestions ?